# Multiple entry points in webpack config in Serverless framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am developing a serverless application using the Serverless Framework. I need webpack to compile the .js files inside root folder as well as 'src' folder. The config file and 'src' folder are right inside root folder. This is the webpack.config.js file

```
var glob = require('glob');
var path = require('path');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

// Required for Create React App Babel transform
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

module.exports = {
  // Use all js files in project root (except
  // the webpack config) as an entry
  entry: globEntries('!(webpack.config).js'),
  target: 'node',
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: __dirname,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }]
  },
  // We are going to create multiple APIs in this guide, and we are 
  // going to create a js file to for each, we need this output block
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
};

function globEntries(globPath) {
  var files = glob.sync(globPath);
  var entries = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var entry = files[i];
    entries[path.basename(entry, path.extname(entry))] = './' + entry;
  }

  return entries;
}
```

Comment: Where is the question? :-)